# Installing my app on iPhone and Android without app store or play store

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I created an app using NativeScript for the small company I work for(Not IT company). I want to find a way for employees to download it without uploading it to either the app store or the play store. What is the best way to do it? I checked online and did not find a recent answer that works.

Comment: try to use Crashlitics beta.

Comment: There are lot of options like Hockeyapp, Testfairy and more. You may even host it on your own server and create a webpage that can handle installation scripts, you will find samples in Google.